# Script isn't working on Coppermine

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gallery

I want to add Backstretch on Coppermine but the script don't seem to work! It works perfectly on Wordpress but not in Coppermine. Here is the Backstretch code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.3/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

<script> 
        $.backstretch([ 
              "http://www.hqdiesel.net/gallery/albums/userpics/10004/hqdiesel9~65.jpg"
            , "http://www.hqdiesel.net/gallery/albums/userpics/10004/selena_hqdiesel7.jpg"
            , "http://www.hqdiesel.net/gallery/albums/userpics/10004/hqdiesel4~132.jpg"
            , "http://www.hqdiesel.net/gallery/albums/userpics/10004/hqdiesel0~106.jpg"
          ], {duration: 5000, fade: 750});
</script>
```

And this is how I applied it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="{LANG_DIR}">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ansi_x3.4-1968">

<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<title>{TITLE}</title>
{META}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coppermine.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/classic_vstrip/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
{JAVASCRIPT}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.3/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

<script> 
        $.backstretch([ 
              "http://www.hqdiesel.net/gallery/albums/userpics/10004/hqdiesel9~65.jpg"
            , "http://www.hqdiesel.net/gallery/albums/userpics/10004/selena_hqdiesel7.jpg"
            , "http://www.hqdiesel.net/gallery/albums/userpics/10004/hqdiesel4~132.jpg"
            , "http://www.hqdiesel.net/gallery/albums/userpics/10004/hqdiesel0~106.jpg"
          ], {duration: 5000, fade: 750});
</script>

<!--
  SVN version info:
  Coppermine version: 1.5.2
  $HeadURL: https://coppermine.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/coppermine/trunk/cpg1.5.x/themes/classic_vstrip/template.html $
  $Revision: 6583 $
  $LastChangedBy: gaugau $
  $Date: 2009-09-16 07:42:37 +0200 (Mi, 16 Sep 2009) $
-->
</head>
<body>GALLERY CODES HERE</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you ♥

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a great description of the problem

Comment: <script> should be <script type="text/javascript"> not so sure if that will fix it, but is the proper way to do it.